How to fix "Invalid JSON payload received" error when updating url_whatsapp attribute in Google Business Profile API?
I am trying to update the url_whatsapp attribute for my business location using the Google Business Profile API. Here's the PATCH request I'm making:
PATCH https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/locations/{locations_id}?attributeMask=url_whatsapp
{
"name": "locations/locationid/attributes",
"attributes": [
{
"name": "url_whatsapp",
"values": ["https://wa.me/74******8"]
}
]
}
{
"error": {
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "attributeMask": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'attributeMask' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "attributes" at 'location': Cannot find field.",
"code": 400,
"details": [
{
"fieldViolations": [
{
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "attributeMask": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'attributeMask' could not be found in request message."
},
{
"field": "location",
"description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "attributes" at 'location': Cannot find field."
}
],
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
}
]
}
}
